# number formatting a class

Tags: c#, .net, razor

I have a class that gets its data from a database and stores it as a string.

`sAnswer` can be any data type, usually an int.  When it is an int, i am trying to get it formatted to have comma separators. (1000000 -> 1,000,000) How can I do this?

using `Format` like `var val = string.Format("{0:n0}", sAnswer);` does not work.

Comment: What do you mean "have comma separators"? You mean if it's a large number like 1000000 it would be formatted to be "1,000,000"?

Comment: that is correct, i will change that in the OP

Answer (score 3):

Formatting happens when converting a value that is NOT a string to a string. You cannot apply formatting to a value that is already a string. You will have to convert the `string` back to an `int` temporarily

```
string val = String.Format("{0:n0}", Int32.Parse(sAnswer));
```

---

You can influence the way `Int32.Parse` tries to convert by using a bitwise combination of `NumberStyles` constants

```
string val = String.Format("{0:n0}", Int32.Parse(sAnswer,
                                                 NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite |
                                                 NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite|
                                                 NumberStyles.AllowExponent));
```

Or simply by using the `NumberStyles.Any` enum constant that gives you a maximum flexibility. If `sAnswer` can contain invalid entries (like an empty string for instance), perform a safe conversion

```
string val;
int i;
if (Int32.TryParse(sAnswer, out i)) {
    val = String.Format("{0:N0}", i);
} else {
    val = ""; // Assign a default value here
}
```

Comment: i get this error: `Input string was not in a correct format.`

Comment: What is in `sAnswer`? It must be a text representing a valid `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you

```
int answerInt;
if (int.TryParse(sAnswer, out answerInt))
{
    sAnswer = answerInt.ToString("#,0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
}
```

Comment: Don't specify a default value for `answerInt` if you plan to overwrite it with the `out` parameter as it just gets thrown away (set to `0`) if it doesn't parse.

Comment: You cannot cast a `string` to an `int`. You will get the exception `"Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'"`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thanks, this shall be the last time I try to answer a question without using the IDE, my memory is like a goldfish these days

Comment: @Corak, yeah good point. There was NO NEED for me to cast twice. I've updated my answer. Cheers bro

Comment: @kane i am getting this error: `Input string was not in a correct format.` with that solution

Comment: @Mike then what *does* you string look like? Because we're working under the impression that `sAnswer = "1000000"`

Comment: @Mike, I have tested this with `sAnswer = "abc"` and `sAnswer = "1000000"` and `sAnswer = "1a"` and all of the results are as expected. You might need to restate your question with the inputs and expected outputs.